# Drawing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, drawing

I'm trying to write something that draws on an image. I have a flow chart that's in a .png and I want to draw a circle around a specific step in the chart based on the page that the user is on. I would normally just head for HTML5 and use the `<canvas>` element, but it has to work on IE8, which doesn't support `<canvas>`. I can use jQuery, but that's the only external library that I can use. Also, the user can scroll up and down the page, so things that I've seen that use absolute positioning end up looking bad since I don't always want the image there. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: You'll likely have to use an image.

Comment: How about a DIV containing the flowchart as a background image with another image (which would be a transparent circle outline image) sitting inside the DIV, positioned absolutely (relative to it's parent DIV) which is moved to the correct position within the div based on which page the user is on. Should be simple enough to do.

Comment: @BillyMoat Good idea. I didn't even think to do that.

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a DIV containing the flowchart as a background image with another image (which would be a transparent circle outline image) sitting inside the DIV, positioned absolutely (relative to it's parent DIV) which is moved to the correct position within the div based on which page the user is on. Should be simple enough to do.